# Twitter Bootstrap HTML form radio button not working with PHP POST

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

For some reason the radio button value from my form is not being passed to the form PHP script on some web browsers when using the Twitter Bootstrap framework.

Form:

```
<form action="" method="post">  
<li class="stream-item stream-header search-input-item">
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span>
<input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" id="appendedInputButton" autocomplete="off" name="q">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
</li>
</div>
<p></p>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="opt" value="1" checked>
  Option 1
</label>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="opt" value="2">
  Option 2
</label>

</form>
```

This the PHP code for collecting the variable is one simple line:

```
$option = $_POST['opt'];
```

This method works absolutely fine with Chrome but doesn't work in IE, Firefox or Opera.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: In your code, action="" - it should point to your script.

Comment: for me have work everywhere, so what's the problem? Post your php code

Comment: @Calle I'm sure the script is submitting to itself, which in that case leaving it blank is what's typically done.

Comment: I have omitted the action="script" <-- It points to the PHP script in my actual code, ive done this for security.

Comment: What is "some web browsers"? Filled `script` with `form.php`, which holds `echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';`
that outputs
`Array
(
    [q] => 
    [opt] => 1
)` in Chrome, FireFox and Opera.

Comment: is either one of the radio button is checked

Answer (score 0):

How are you submitting the data? I cannot see a submit button.

The code works fine for me in FF using the following (notice I added a submit button):

```
<form action="" method="post">  
<li class="stream-item stream-header search-input-item">
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span>
<input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" id="appendedInputButton" autocomplete="off" name="q">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
</li>
</div>
<p></p>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="opt" value="1" checked>
  Option 1
</label>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="opt" value="2">
  Option 2
</label>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >

</form>
```

Result from print_r($_POST);

```
Array ( [q] => [opt] => 1 [submit] => submit )
```