# Radio button data not being submitted

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm using Bootstrap in addition to this, I simply want to know if ductless_no or ductless_yes is selected, why is this value not showing up in my POST data?

```
    <div id="ductless">
        <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Ductless Minisplit<span style="color:#F00;">*</span></span>
                <div style="margin-left:20px;" name="reset12" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                  <label class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('#pu').collapse('show');$('#no_drop').collapse('show');" >
                    <input type="radio" name="ductless_no" value="1" > No
                  </label>
                  <label class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('#pu').collapse('hide');$('#no_drop').collapse('hide');" >
                    <input type="radio" name="ductless_yes" value="1" > Yes
                  </label>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Neither ductless_no or ductless_yes are being set

Just to elaborate further...this is one part in a huge form, the form is being sent however when doing a var_dump on the $_POST data neither ductless_no or ductless_yes are showing as selected when I select them.

Thanks for the downvotes that helps

Comment: For the love of god, don't ever use inline javascript/jquery

Comment: Agreed with @RUJordan -- It's ugly, and it hurts the hell out of the next person that has to maintain the code.

Comment: Is it in a form? Cause it doesn't look like it. If it's not in a form that's the reason why there is no post data

Answer (score 0):

Similar question: [Twitter Bootstrap HTML form radio button not working with PHP POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204181/twitter-bootstrap-html-form-radio-button-not-working-with-php-post)

There can only be one option selected. Give each radio button the same name of "ductlessYesNo" and a different value... I have given 1 for no and 2 for yes.

```
<label class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('#pu').collapse('show');$('#no_drop').collapse('show');" >

                <input type="radio" name="ductlessYesNo" value="1" > No

              </label>

              <label class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('#pu').collapse('hide');$('#no_drop').collapse('hide');" >

                <input type="radio" name="ductlessYesNo" value="2" > Yes

              </label>
```